# cannot find //=require jquery.nouislider in application.css

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, pipeline, assets

Im trying to use a few slider gems and I keep bumping into the same problem,

https://github.com/soycamo/jquery-nouislider-rails

I follow the instructions to put in app/assets/javascript manifest file:

//=require jquery.nouislider

In the app/assets/stylesheets manifest file:

//=require jquery.nouislider

I have also installed the gem. However I keep getting error messages that say:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/foodin/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised: 
couldn't find file 'jquery.nouislider'
(in /home/ubuntu/foodin/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:16)

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I think this might be related to the asset pipeline but im not sure. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: This is my development.rb config file incase its something to do with that:

```
Foodin::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

#NEW: Added for Devise
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

#New:Added for development
config.serve_static_assets = false

end
```

Comment: may be you need to restart server if you just installed gem

Comment: tried that but im still getting the error described below :s

Comment: There is some issue with Gem. Its not working for me also. Use by downloading the files and save in respective assets directory.

Comment: Do you mean download the gem or actually do it manually with the javascript files?

Comment: Yes, unfortuantely you have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css it should be

```
*= require jquery.nouislider
```

and not

```
//= require jquery.nouislider
```

and try to replace Gemfile declarations with;

`gem 'jquery-nouislider-rails', '~> 4.0.1.1'` specifying  the version and restart server

**Working setup**

I simple [downloaded nonuislider here](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/download) and added it to app/assets/javascripts folder then called it in application.js as you had done before and it worked. Maybe there is something wrong with the Gem.

Comment: I have made that change and now it gives me a similar error for the js file -  Showing /home/ubuntu/foodin/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery.nouislider'
  (in /home/ubuntu/foodin/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)

Comment: that line is this: <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: try `//= require jquery.nouislider` with the space between the file name and declaration

Comment: no luck, im sure its something really simple but I just don't know what it is :s

Comment: I used the following://
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.nouislider

Comment: Try reorganising with bootstrap towards the end like this //= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require jquery.nouislider
//= require turbolinks 
//= require twitter/bootstrap 
//= require_tree .

Comment: I used the updated gem 'jquery-nouislider-rails', '~> 4.0.1.1' but i still have the same issue

Comment: I also just tried with the rearranged order and its still the same issue. Could it be something to do with asset pipeline? I tried two different slider gems and it was the same issue with both

Comment: added the development.rb file to the question just incase

Comment: @Cookiejest, i have shared how i go it to work. If it works for you then you can mark it as answered for everyone trying to do the same.

Comment: ok i will try that now, shouldnt these files be in vendor/ directory though?

Comment: Cookiejest how did you manage to solve it? I am having actually the same error

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but it seems that your Gem is not up to date.

You can try this fork for noUiSlider:

https://github.com/chug2k/nouislider-rails

or this for Seiyria's Slider:

https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-slider-rails/versions/6.0.17

Happy sliding :-)